# Obtain Wireless Debugging Port Number Programatically

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-wifi

I need to get the IP address and port listed under wireless debugging option from android app. I found out that the IP address can be obtained from `applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE).connectionInfo`. However there doesn't seem to be any way to get the port number from the connectionInfo.

Is it possible to also get the wireless debugging port number programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Found this. Hope it helps.

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/adb-wifi-how-to-specify-port-and-have-it-fix.4321669/

Solution:
After using the quick tile to enable wireless debugging, you can use nmap (and awk) on your debug workstation to discover the open port to run "adb connect :" with:

1. set Android 11/12/etc. to static IP. If you use DHCP ... you'll have to also discover the DHCP IP of your device. A static DHCP lease will also suffice to make things easy on you if you must rely on DHCP for the particular network you're accessing. In any event, you must be able to know or discover the IP address of your device in order to make this work.
2. turn on wireless debugging - you'll note that it changes the port every time wireless debugging is toggled on.
3. The ports are supposedly always within the range of 30000 to 49999.
4. since we have the IP and the port range, we can use nmap to obtain the listening port. So this step is to install nmap and awk if you dont have those commands (run "nmap" and "awk" on their own to see if you have them in your path)
5. run this code - set PHONE= to the static IP of your device. Mine is set to 192.168.19.19, so:
   PHONE=192.168.19.19
   adb connect ${PHONE}:$( nmap -sT ${PHONE} -p30000-49999 | awk -F/ '/tcp open/{print $1}' )
6. it should connect with something like this message:
   connected to 192.168.19.19:42699

this is not a perfect solution if you happen to have other apps that open a listening TCP port in those ranges... but you could also filter those specific ports out with the nmap range. Most people won't be in this boat, but its probably worth mentioning for someones sake.